# MySQL Error: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/php-error-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

I am getting the following error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource`

My query seems fine, here is my code:

```
function products()
{
  $query = "SELECT id, quantity, price FROM dvd WHERE quantity > 0";
    if (!$query) 
    {
      echo "no product found";
      die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
      while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "Test";
    }
  }
}
```

What does that error mean?

Comment: Where is the mysql_connect()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to execute the query:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is just the text of the query.  Change it to:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id, quantity, price FROM dvd WHERE quantity > 0");
```

Comment: oops, sorry for making a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `mysql_query()` which actually executes it.

Replace the `$query = ...;` line with this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, quantity, price FROM dvd WHERE quantity > 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a result from the query first...

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

... Then pass `$result` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```